# Alignment of listbox

Tags: python, listbox, tkinter

I'm getting vertical alignment of  entries while using the following code

```
from Tkinter import *
import tkMessageBox
import Tkinter
top = Tk()
Lb1 = Listbox(top)
Lb1.insert(1, "Python")
Lb1.insert(2, "Perl")
Lb1.insert(3, "C")
Lb1.insert(4, "PHP")
Lb1.insert(5, "JSP")
Lb1.insert(6, "Ruby")
Lb1.pack()
top.mainloop()
```

Is it possible to allign listbox entries horizontally? or any other widget can be used for it??

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually a separate listbox is used for each item (especially if you want to select one option from one category).  Note that the size that width= uses depends on the font size, and that the distances will be close but not exact unless you use a fixed width font ("i" takes up the same amount of space as "w").

```
from Tkinter import *
top = Tk()

for lit in ("Python", "Perl", "C", "PHP", "JSP", "Ruby"):
    lb=Listbox(top,width=10)
    lb.pack(side=LEFT)
    lb.insert(1, lit)

top.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `grid` geometry manager to lay things out in a grid, or you can pass a value in for the `side` parameter using `pack` (eg: `Lb1.pack(side="left")`)